# Metadata in ArcExplorer

Tags: metadata, arcgis-explorer

Is it possible to access feature class' metadata in ArcGIS Explorer?
I noticed the [ArcGIS Idea](https://c.na9.visual.force.com/apex/ideaView?id=087E00000004GmY) but not sure if it has been implemented..

Answer (score 1):

Free Geoportal Add-ons

These Esri Geoportal Server add-ons add new levels of interoperability between geoportals and ArcGIS for Desktop or ArcGIS Explorer. There are clients for data publishing and data search and discovery.

CSW Clients for ArcGIS

The CSW Clients for ArcGIS let you discover and use GIS resources available through a geoportal directly from ArcGIS for Desktop or ArcGIS Explorer. Use the clients to

Search metadata catalogs directly from ArcMap or ArcGIS Explorer.
View the title and abstract of search results and download the metadata XML.
Add live map services to ArcMap or ArcGIS Explorer.
ArcGIS for Desktop 10 is required to install the ArcMap component of the CS-W clients for ArcGIS.

The CSW Client for ArcGIS Explorer requires ArcGIS Explorer Build 1200 or higher.